# How to make a GET call to api.github with Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, express

I'm blocked since 3 days and did my research on the internet. Here' is the code.

**api.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
var http = require('http');
var https = require("https");

router.get('/github', async function (req, res) {
    https.get('https://api.github.com/v3/users/tmtanzeel', function (apiRes) {
        apiRes.pipe(res);

    }).on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(e);
        res.status(500).send('Something went wrong');
    });
});
```

**Output:**

> Request forbidden by administrative rules. Please make sure your request has a User-Agent header (http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required). Check https://developer.github.com for other possible causes.

I found something useful here:

1. [In Node.js/Express, how do I automatically add this header to every "render" response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661151/in-node-js-express-how-do-i-automatically-add-this-header-to-every-render-res)
2. [Requesting https://api.github.com/users (api) returns System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden IsSuccessStatusCode = false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233113/requesting-https-api-github-com-users-api-returns-system-net-httpstatuscode)

But these were not very helpful.

I tried: `res.setHeader("User-Agent", "My App");` but I'm not very sure about the second argument.

Modified **server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const api = require('./routes/api');
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    res.setHeader("User-Agent", "My App"); // <-------------ADDED HEADER HERE

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});

app.use('/api', api);
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Server is up and running!');
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on 3000 port');
});
```

Have you ever face this kind of issue. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting headers to your response. Instead, you must set headers in the API call you make. You can pass `options` object to the `http.get()` method and set headers there.

```
router.get('/github', async function (req, res) {

    const options = {
       hostname: 'api.github.com',
       path: '/v3/users/tmtanzeel',
       headers: {
           'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1521.3 Safari/537.36'
       }
    }

    https.get(options, function (apiRes) {
        apiRes.pipe(res);

    }).on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(e);
        res.status(500).send('Something went wrong');
    });
});
```

See this answer on setting github user-agent header:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16954033/4185234

Comment: I was reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Comment: Now I'm getting `{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
}
`  However I've added  `const options = {
        hostname: 'api.github.com',
        path: '/v3/users/tmtanzeel',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': ...,
        OAuth: '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'
    }`

Comment: I think I'll do some more document reading at : https://docs.github.com/rest

Comment: Since you've answered the actual question I'm accepting this answer. But please look into my other issue (that i mentioned above) if you've time. I need expert help real bad.